# Active Class Based On Selected Menu in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, class, indexing

I'm learning angular and try to create a navbar menu and set 'active' class based on current page.
i've seen this solution here: [Active Class Based On Selected Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502575/active-class-based-on-selected-menu) but want to know the equivalent solution in angular 7 and typescript.
please how to achieve that in angular 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "routerLinkActive" directive like -

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
```

See the following reference - 
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive